# Suppose $f(X) \subseteq B$. Show that $f : (X, \mathcal{A}) \to (Y, \mathcal{B})$ is measurable iff $f: X \to (Y, \mathcal{B}_B)$ is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

> Let $(X, \mathcal{A})$ and $(Y, \mathcal{B})$ be measurable spaces and $f: X \to Y$. Let $B \in \mathcal{B}$ and suppose $f(X) \subseteq B$. Show that $f : (X, \mathcal{A}) \to (Y,  \mathcal{B})$ is measurable iff $f: (X, \mathcal{A})  \to (Y, \mathcal{B}_B)$ is measurable, where $\mathcal{B}_B$ is the restriction of $\mathcal{B}$ to $B$.

Suppose that $f : (X, \mathcal{A}) \to (Y,  \mathcal{B})$ is measruable, then for any $E \in \mathcal{B}$ the set $f^{-1}(E) \in \mathcal{A}$. In particular for any $E \in \mathcal{B}_B$ the set $f^{-1}(E) \in \mathcal{A}$, thus $f: (X, \mathcal{A})  \to (Y, \mathcal{B}_B)$ is measurable.

Conversely suppose that $f: (X, \mathcal{A})  \to (Y, \mathcal{B}_B)$ is measurable. Now since $f(X) \subseteq B \implies X \subset f^{-1}(B)$, but what does this tell me? For every set $E \in \mathcal{B}$ the preimage $f^{-1}(E)$, is $\emptyset$ if it's not in $B$?

Comment: Notice that $\mathcal B_B=\{B\cap C\mid C\in \mathcal B\}$. So, if $f:X\to (Y,\mathcal B_B)$ is measurable, then for all $C\in \mathcal B$, $f^{-1}(C\cap B)$ is measurable. In particular, for all $C\in \mathcal B$, you have that $f^{-1}(C)=f^{-1}(C)\cap X=f^{-1}(C)\cap f^{-1}(B)=f^{-1}(C\cap B)$ is measurable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $E\in\mathcal{B}$, write
$$
E=(E\cap B)\cup (E\cap B^c),
$$
where each set in the union belongs to $\mathcal{B}$. Then
$$
f^{-1}(E)=f^{-1}(E\cap B)\cup f^{-1}(E\cap B^c)= f^{-1}(E\cap B)\cup \emptyset.
$$
Notice that $f^{-1}(E\cap B)\in\mathcal{B}\mid_B$, and therefore, $f^{-1}(E\cap B)\in\mathcal{B}$, i.e., $f$ is $\mathcal{A}/\mathcal{B}$-measurable.

Comment: This is for the former implication?